# Windows 8 UI in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles

I'm trying to get a windows-8-like style on my website, but there is something wrong with the aligning of the divs. When a big square is put into the design, the other (smaller) rectangles and squares are put aside in a wrong way.. I've made a jsfiddle to show you the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/CGX7S/

I have tried to use float and then clear every line, but i think this can't be the ideal solution.

```
float:left
```

Can you help me out? Do i have to do a trick with jquery, javascript, floats or css?

Comment: "...the other (smaller) rectangles and squares." do WHAT? And what do you want them to do?

Comment: I want to have the smaller squares to fill up the remaining space right next to the big square. I forgot to finish that sentence, sorry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve that in many ways, the simplest, for now, is a masonry plugin [masonry pluging page](http://masonry.desandro.com/). On that page you can find documentation, examples everything. Have fun.